# How can I convert the URL of an image to base64 (IONIC 2)

Tags: cordova, ionic2

Help,  How can I convert the URL of an image to base64 (IONIC 2)

```
this.camera.getPicture({


sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  quality: 100,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
}).then(imageData => {
  console.log('THIS IS THE URI ' + imageData);
  //How do I get the image and convert it to base64 ?
}, error => {
  this.error = JSON.stringify(error);
});
```

Comment: did the solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
this.camera.getPicture({
sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  quality: 100,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
}).then(imageData => {
  console.log('THIS IS THE Base64' + imageData);
  let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
}, error => {
  this.error = JSON.stringify(error);
});
```

**destinationType** supports following 3 options:

1. **DATA_URL** : Return base64 encoded string. DATA_URL can be very memory intensive and cause app crashes or out of memory errors. Use FILE_URI or NATIVE_URI if possible
2. **FILE_URI** : Return file uri (content://media/external/images/media/2 for Android)
3. **NATIVE_URI** : Return native uri (eg. asset-library://... for iOS)